# Hide Tablayout in some Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I would like to hide my Tablayout in some Fragments my app will show up. One solution would be setting the android:aylout_height attribute of the TabLayout to eiher "0dp" or "wrap_content". But how do I set the height to 0dp programmatically? Is that even possible with a TabLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fragments that you want your `TabLayout` to not show...

```
tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I would put the above part of your code in your fragment's `onCreateView()` method.

Then, in fragments where you want it to show again:

```
tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

xml:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

code:

```
TableLayout layout= (TableLayout ) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_table);// change id here
layout.setVisibility(View.GONE); //VIEW.VISIBLE etc.
```

Comment: I would like to ask about this matter, is it the best way for this outcome? when we want a layout with tabs and a layout without tabs it is the best approach to hide tabhost? or there is also another better way to replace for this fragment only the viewpager with a single fragment?